# Write a bitmap stored in memory into a file

Tags: c, bitmap, bmp

I have to write a function which create a bitmap file from an Image struct. This Image struct contains only an array of pixel, the height and width of the image. Here is the struct Image:

```
typedef struct{
      unsigned char blue;   /*!<the blue component */
      unsigned char green;  /*!<the green component */
      unsigned char red;    /*!<the red component */
}Pixel;

typedef struct{
      int width;    /*!<the number of columns in the pixel grid*/
      int height;   /*!<the number of lines in the pixel grid*/
      Pixel * raw_data; /*!<the pixel grid*/
}Image;
```

Here is my function to create a file:

```
void writeBMPFile(char* filename, Image* image)
{
    FILE* f = fopen(filename, "wb+");
    FileHeader f_header;
    DIBHeader  d_header;
    char padding;
    int i;

    if(f == NULL)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "The file %s could not be opened", filename);
        exit(0);
    }

    if (((image->width * d_header.nbBitPerPixel/8) % 4) != 0)
        padding = 4 - ((image->width * d_header.nbBitPerPixel/8) % 4);
    else
        padding = 0;

    d_header = createDibHeader(image->height, image->width);
    f_header = createFileHeader(d_header, padding);

    fwrite(&f_header, sizeof(FileHeader), 1, f);
    fwrite(&d_header, d_header.size_DIBHeader, 1, f);

    for (i = 0; i < d_header.image_height; i++)
    {
        fwrite(image->raw_data + i*d_header.image_height,
               d_header.nbBitPerPixel/8, d_header.image_width, f);
        if(padding != 0)
            fwrite(NULL, 1, padding, f);
    }
    fclose(f);
}
```

My problem concerns the padding in the file. I suspect it is not correctly written in the file. I tried to write an image of cross. This is what it looks like when there is no padding (152*152):

[image]

The same image with padding this time (151*151):

[image]

The second image (151*151) should look like the first picture, a blue cross on a red background. I'm pretty sure my problem comes from padding but can't figure out what i'm doing wrong. Can anybody tell me where is my problem ?

Comment: `fwrite(NULL, 1, padding, f);` is definitely wrong. You tell `fwrite` to write `1 * padding` bytes from `NULL`. It will dereference the null pointer and lead to undefined behavior. If you want to write a set of bytes then you need an actual array or pointer to some actual memory your process owns, of the correct size. For example something like `const uint8_t padding_data[padding] = { 0 };`. That will create an array of bytes of `padding` elements, each element initialized to zero.

Comment: Thank you! This solved my problem. I should have thought about it considering the program segfaulted at this line.